# SIM800 close the FTP GET session lonely

Tags: c, ftp, stm32, sim800

I am using SIM868 for a project. Exactly I am using FTP.
After setting the bearer configuration, opened it and setting all the FTP paramaters (like Server address, User name, password..) and when I am trying to open the GET session with (AT+FTPGET=1) the response is like this (+FTPGET:1,80)
I checked many application note and I found that (80) is used for FTP Quit session. So I didn't understand why FTP close the GET session when I am trying to opened it. If I am wrong and the (80) It's not a FTP QUIT session, so what's wrong?
Best regards,

Comment: First test your ftp server through some PC based utility/FTP client. Check if its working OK.

Comment: I tested it and it's okay. Now I find that (80) is "SSL failed to establish channels"

Comment: Does your server needs SSL encrypted connection? Does your modem have SSL capability? If yes then check how to enable SSL of modem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the type of server. My server was SFTP, and sim868 support FTPSSL. You can find the difference here: https://www.goanywhere.com/blog/2016/11/23/sftp-vs-ftps-the-key-differences